# How to add fonts to FopFactoryBuilder configuration at runtime from resources folder?

Tags: java, apache-fop

I need a solution where I read files from my resources folder and add them to FOP Factory builder like this,

```
FopFactoryBuilder fopFactoryBuilder = new FopFactoryBuilder(getImageBase()).setConfiguration(cfg);
FontManager fM = fopFactoryBuilder.getFontManager();
//Read font from here and add it to fonts cache for FOP to use;
eg Font manager . Add/Register font
```

My application has been working with the fop config file but now I need to deploy it where I have no specific full absolute path to my fonts so I have to embed them in the app and load them to Font Manager in FOP. Any help